# Delete entire line if it contains specific word

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I also want to display the line containing the word. I want to open an external .txt file and delete any line if it contains a specific string. I have a search and replace at the moment for one word but want the entire line to be removed from the file. Thanks

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myStreamReaderL1 As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim myStream As System.IO.StreamWriter

    Dim myStr As String
    myStreamReaderL1 = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:\Users\f1r1a\Desktop\memes.txt")
    myStr = myStreamReaderL1.ReadToEnd()
    myStreamReaderL1.Close()


    myStr = myStr.Substring("fraser", 6)
    'Save myStr
    myStream = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\Users\f1r1a\Desktop\memes.txt")
    myStream.WriteLine(myStr)
    myStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do all of that code in two lines

```
Dim  result = File.ReadLines("C:\Users\f1r1a\Desktop\memes.txt").
                   Where(Function(x) Not x.Contains("fraser"))
File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\f1r1a\Desktop\memes.txt", result.ToArray)
```

The IEnumerable extension *Where* receives, line by line, the sequence produced by *File.ReadLines*. Each line is processed by *Where* applying the *Contains* method and if the line doesn't contains the word searched then it is passed as output to the result variable. In turn the result variable is passed as an array to the *WriteAllLines* method.

Comment: Thanks that does exactly what i want. Is there a way where i could just put the line that contains that word into a textbox? thanks

Comment: Of course, you could add a textbox to your form and when you press the button you read the content of the textbox.   _Dim search = txtSearch.Text_ and then use the variable search in place of the constant _fraser_

Comment: not quite  i mean so it searches for the line containing fraser and then puts that into a textbox on the screen

Comment: That's the contrary of the question. Just remove the Not in front of x.Contains and you will have a list of all lines that Contains the word. Then you can put these lines in a multiline textbox using _txtLines.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result)_

Answer (score 1):

You can get both at once:

```
Dim file = "C:\Users\f1r1a\Desktop\memes.txt"

Dim lookup = File.ReadLines(file).ToLookup(Function(l) l.Contains("fraser"))

textBoxRemoved.Text = String.Join("|", lookup(True))

File.WriteAllLines(file, lookup(False))
```